# Incorrect URL accessed

Tags: javascript, html, url, href

I am trying to implement a feature that will open a new window to a link when an icon is clicked, but the icon click keeps accessing the wrong URL. Instead of redirecting to the URL in its `href` upon clicking the icon, it redirects to the CDC Home page. My current attempt of trying to implement this feature only uses HTML code as can be seen in the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tsbaoLr1/, but I'm uncertain as to why this issue keeps happening, let alone how to fix it.

How can I get this implementation to redirect to the correct URL upon clicking the icon?

P.S. This issue has been replicated on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox.

Comment: Try adding `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to your anchor tag. I'm not sure but I guess this website is performing some referral checks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this to be an issue on the side of CDC's website.

In your form, if you remove the 's' from https:// so that it is http:// it redirects successfully to the page you want. (Worry not, it automatically gets converted to a secure https link once it redirects).

In addition, if you right click the hyperlink and open in new incognito window, while using a https request, it also opens the requested web page, confirming that this may be an issue on CDC's side.